# pandas read csv by taking samples

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a large CSV file and I just want to take a 1% sample from it.  Is there a good way to read the samples directly into pandas data frame without having to read the whole file and then discard 99% of the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the number of lines are large enough for the law of large #'s to take effect, and you don't need it to be exactly 1% (just very close to it), you could do the following:

```
import csv
from random import random
import pandas
with open('data.csv', 'r') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    rows = [l for l in reader if random() >= 0.99]
    df = pandas.DataFrame(rows)
```

This will sequentially scan the whole file once to get the lines but it won't keep the whole file in memory. It will iterate through the lines one by one, and only keep in memory the ~1% of lines that are randomly selected. If you don't want to load the file into memory, and don't want to scan it to count lines first, then this is probably best.

If you do need it to be exactly 1% of the lines, and/or need it to work for smaller files too, then you can scan the file once to count the total number of lines in the file `total_lines`. Then generate a set of `0.01 * total_lines` random line numbers that are <= the total # lines. Then you use the method above, and as you iterate through the lines in the file, you just check to see if the line # you're currently on is in the `set()` and keep it if so, toss it otherwise:

```
import csv
import random
import pandas
with open('/home/jess/code/examples/testdata.csv', 'r') as fin:
    total_lines = sum(1 for line in fin)
    num_lines = int(0.01 * total_lines)
    selected_lines = set(random.sample(range(total_lines), num_lines))
    fin.seek(0) # reset cursor back to beginning of file for CSV reader
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    rows = []
    curr_line = 0
    for row in reader:
        if curr_line in selected_lines:
            rows.append(row)
        curr_line += 1

    df = pandas.DataFrame(rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use skiprows with a complex selector:

Example would be 
`rows=1000
prob=.01
print len(pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=[0], skiprows=lambda x: x in random.sample(xrange(0,num_rows), int((1.0-prob)*num_rows ))))`

There are also other ways of doing it by reading in chunks and then just skipping rows.
e.g. you could use `chunksize=100
skiprows=99`